# Disable GPIO by default and temporarily activate it via python script

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, gpio

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 2 with DietPi and plugged in an alarm module into the GPIO 14 (Pin 08).

I would now like to disable this Pin by default and only allow it to turn on temporarily within my python script.

So far I've tried using RPi.GPIO which hasn't worked and unexport/export but this only ended up damaging my os to an extend where I had to reinstall it.

Clearly I am doing something very wrong. Does anyone have experience with this and could point me in the right direction?

Comment: What do you expect by *"disabling"* a GPIO?  You haven't clearly defined the problem.  Is this GPIO used for input or output?  If there's a device attached and the GPIO is used as an output, then *"disabling"* the GPIO is the wrong thing to do.  I.E. you're allowing the output to be in an undefined state, and therefore lost control of the device.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have my rpi with me, but you can try using this.
First function exports, 3 following check time

```
import time
import sys

def unexport(gpio):
  value = open("/sys/class/gpio/unexport","w")
  value.write(gpio)
  value.close()

def checkHours:
    return int(time.strftime("%l"))

def checkMinutes:
    return int(time.strftime("%M"))

def checkAMorPM:
    return time.strftime("%p")

def disableGpio3AM46:
    if (checkHours == 3) and (checkMinutes == 46) and (checkAMorPM == 'PM'):
        print 'amazing'
        unexport(gpio)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since posting this question I've figured out this way to disable and enable the pin/gpio through python:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(8, GPIO.OUT)

try:
    while True:
    GPIO.output(8,1)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    GPIO.output(8,0)
    time.sleep(0.5)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
    print "Bye"
```

All that's left for me to figure out now is how to disable the pinby default so that alarm won't play until the code is run